# Mako NameError, Not Evaluating For Loop

Tags: python, pycharm, mako

I'm using a Mako template but keep on receiving a NameError when trying to iterate through the for loop below where dict_list is passed into `template.render(dict_list = dict_list)`

```
%for item in dict_list:
    <td>${item}</td> 
    <td>${item}</td>  
    <td>${item}</td>
%endfor
```

with the error being returned being `NameError: 'item' is not defined` . Running a for loop in a Python code block like `<% for item in dict_list: print (item) %>` works as expected.

Comment: why are you printing the same item multiple times???

Comment: Those are just placeholders. I would edit what's being returned but just wanted to check if something was returned

Comment: I think there should be a space between `%` and the rest of the line

Comment: Tried with a space and same error